# Find and list all char clusters in the string C++

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

I'm looking for some help finding all clusters of chars in the string in C++. The exact task is:

> Given the following “2D string” (in C++ expression):

```
string text =
  "#################aa##a###c######\n" +
  "####bbbbaaaabbbbbaaaaa###ccc##cc\n" +
  "#o##bbbbaaaabbbbbaaaaa###c#c##cc\n" +
  "#oo#bbbbaeeabbbbbbbbaa##cc#ccccc\n" +
  "#o##bbbbaeeabbbbbaaaaaa#cc#####c\n" +
  "#o##bbbbaaaabbbbbaaaaaa#cc#####c\n";
```

> Write a program computing the area of each contiguous region of the same >symbols. Two equal symbols belong to the same area if they are neighbors either >in a row or in a column. Don’t count the newline (\n) symbols, they are just to >form the 2D string.
>
> The main function should be recursive.
>
> Hint: use an extra 2D array to mark each symbol in the 2D string if it is >already counted or not. Scan the array row-wise until a not counted yet symbol >is found. Then, run the recursive area-computing function starting from this >symbol. Continue until all symbols are marked as counted.
>
> The program output should look (more or less) like:

```
Region of symbols #, area …
Region of symbols a, area …
Region of symbols #, area …
Region of symbols c, area …
```

My current code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int cords (string str, int x, int y) {
    int length, i, position, lines = 0, x_max, y_max;
    char symbol;
    length = str.length();
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        symbol = str[i];
        if (symbol == '\n')
            lines++;
    }
    length -= lines;
    x_max = length / lines;
    y_max = length / x_max;
    position = x - 1 + (y - 1) * x_max + y - 1;

    if (x <= x_max && y <= y_max)
        return position;
}

int clusterMiner (char symbol, string str, int x, int y, int counter, int last) {
    if (x > 32 || y > 6) {
        return counter;
    } else {
        if (str[cords(str, x++, y)] == symbol) {
            counter++;
            return clusterMiner(symbol, str, x++, y, counter, x);
        } else if (str[cords(str, 1, y++)] == symbol) {
            return clusterMiner(symbol, str, 1, y++, counter, x);
        }
    }
}

int main () {
    int length, lines, i, j, k, l, counter;
    string text = // 32 elements per line
    "#################aa##a###c######\n" // 32
    "####bbbbaaaabbbbbaaaaa###ccc##cc\n" // 64
    "#o##bbbbaaaabbbbbaaaaa###c#c##cc\n" // 96
    "#oo#bbbbaeeabbbbbbbbaa##cc#ccccc\n" // 128
    "#o##bbbbaeeabbbbbaaaaaa#cc#####c\n" // 160 
    "#o##bbbbaaaabbbbbaaaaaa#cc#####c\n"; // 192

    counter = clusterMiner('#', text, 1, 1, 0, 0);
    cout << counter;

    return 0;
}
```

Cords function is just for easier interaction with the two dimensions of the string.

I'm not sure what to do next. Right now the program counts only some of the symbols as it stops at the first different one ignoring these which are connected to further nodes.

Thanks!

Comment: Just a small hint: It could be helpful to store somewhere whether you already "visited" (i.e. counted) a certain character. Then from every character, you can inspect all of the 4 neighboring characters that you haven't visited yet. Watch out for the borders, so you don't read memory outside your text.

Answer (score 0):

First, do not calculate x_max and y_max all the time newly, just do it once and store it in a variable. Then, you will have to iterate over the whole field:

```
char get(int x, int y)
{
    // + 1: the newline!!!
    return field[x + y * (x_max + 1)];
}

void countAll()
{
    calculateMaxima();
    // created your visited array now
    for(unsigned int y = 0; y <= y_max; ++y)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x <= x_max; ++x)
        {
            if(!visited[x, y])
            {
                count = 0;
                search(get(x, y), x, y);
                // output count here...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Each time we hit a character not yet visited, i. e. a new one, we start a new search. For each search, we have to consider four neighbours for each current position `{x, y}`:
`{x +/- 1, y}` and `{x, y +/- (x_max + 1}` (apart from the positions at the edges, which have less). So your search might look like this:

```
void visit(char symbol, int x, int y)
{
    if(!visited[x][y] && get(x, y) == symbol)
    {
        ++count;
        ++visited[x][y] = true;
    }
    search(symbol, x, y);
}

void search(char symbol, int x, int y)
{
    if(x > 0)
        visit(x - 1, y);
    if(x < max_x)
        visit(x + 1, y);
    if(y > 0)
        visit(x, y - 1);
    if(y < max_y)
        visit(x, y + 1);
}
```

For now, I am assuming count, visited and x/y_max being some global variables. Cleaner, as we are C++, would be writing a separate class for this purpose:

```
class ClusterMiner
{
    unsigned int count;
    std::string field;
    // ...

    void visit(char symbol, int x, int y);
    void search(char symbol, int x, int y);
    // ...
public:
    void countAll();
};
```

Code is untested and incomplete, it shall only give you the necessary hints to find your way...

Side note: If you have unconnected regions of the same character, these will be detected as such. If this is not desired, you might sum up the results e. g. in a `std::map<char, unsigned int>` and iterate over this one after you finished counting...